# Installing Ubuntu on HP Envy4-1030us

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I am having an issue I can't quite get around. I just got a new HP Envy4-1030us with Windows 7 on it, and the first thing I did was upgrade to Windows 8. So now I'm trying to partition the 500GB drive and install Ubuntu, but when I get into the installer there are no drives to install it to. Also, palimpsest thinks the drive is formatted in FAT, when Windows is telling me that it's NTFS. Any ideas? There are only two partitions, the Windows 8 one, and the "system reserved".

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the live image lacks the required RAID drivers that are required to see the drives on a system using the Intel Rapid Storage Technology. In order for me to actually get this installed, I had to wipe all the drives, including the 32GB ssd, reinstall Windows, then Ubuntu, then install the Intel Rapid Storage Technology in Windows to get that working again. Quite a pain...